# SQL injection vulnerability- myBatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

We use MyBatis in our code to map objects with SQL statements.

Our recent SSAP scan shows, the below code vulnerable:

```
ORDER BY ${columnName}
```

The above code is not available for user queries and is not exposed to the user. There are proper entitlements for each table and attribute before the queries are compiled.

MyBatis URL says:

> Here MyBatis won't modify or escape the string.
>
> NOTE It's not safe to accept input from a user and supply it to a
>   statement unmodified in this way. This leads to potential SQL
>   Injection attacks and therefore **you should either disallow user input
>   in these fields**, or always perform your own escapes and checks.

Ref:http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Question: Is the above vulnerability false positive?

P.S. Above code is an example and is similarly used at 'n' number of places so modifying it will be a massive effort.

Comment: Who can say w/o looking at your code?

Comment: As you said above you're mapping class objects to sql queries and **not** user input to queries then we can conclude that it is a false positive.

Comment: If `${columnName}` cannot currently be replaced directly by user entered code then yes it's a false positive. What's the likelihood of this not happening in future though?